# How to compare string to Dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary

Hey I am struggling to check for matching links.
Links.txt contains links and `img` is a string with a link inside.
What I want to do with my for loop is to skip over the links that are already in the Links.txt file OR is not 115 characters long.
The part where is checking for `len()` seems to be functioning right but even if the `src` is equal to a link in the file it still stops the loop and a duplicated link is written in the file.

```
img=page_soup.findAll("img")
convert_links= open("Links.txt","r+")
dic={}

for line in convert_links:
    (key) = line
    dic[key] = line

    
for index,link in enumerate(img):
    src= link["src"]
    if src in dic or len(src)!=115:
        print("Found")
    else:
        break

links_file.write(links_file.read() + "\n"+src)
urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, "firstmeme.jpg")

convert_links.close()
```

Comment: Presuming your `Links.txt` file has the keys on different lines you have a newline character on the back of the line, and thus on the back of your key. Edit: try `dic[key] = line.strip()`

Comment: `if src in dic.keys() ...` should work, but make sure the key has no new lines on it when making the dictionary with [`line.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip).

Comment: Whoa...missed something else. You actually loading dic with the same value for both the key and value? Not sure I understand what you meant to do, but thinking you should use a set instead of a dict there.

Comment: using `else: break` is not good idea because it will execute `break` on first not matching elements and it will not check other elements. You have to do it in different way. inside `else:` you should run code which uses  this link.

Comment: @furas I want to break even if one element that is unique and 115 characters long is found.

Comment: @AndrewAllaire Doesn't seem to work , sadly. Links are still being repeated

Comment: so you want skip all links when you find one matching link ? OR you want to skip only this one matching link ? If first version you would need to set `found = False` before `for`-loop and set `found = True` inside `for`-loop and after loop check `if not found: ....`. If you want to skip only matching links then inside `else:` you should write new link and download image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's prepare the data from the file.

- We aren't actually interested in using a key value to look up a link; we're just interested in having unique links. So the data structure we want is `set`, not `dict`.
- We need to strip trailing newlines (and possibly other whitespace) off the end of the file lines.
- Instead of writing a loop to append things to an empty container, we can build the data we want directly with a comprehension.
- We only read from the file, so we can just open in `'r'` mode - which is the default.

Also, we should use a `with` block to manage closing the file.

So:

```
with open("Links.txt") as f:
    links_in_file = {line.rstrip() for line in f}
```

Then, we can use this to filter the links from the webpage.

- We again presumably don't want any duplicates, even if the file doesn't have them. So again we want a `set`.
- Just printing a "Found" message isn't very helpful; let's actually build a set that has the undesired values filtered out. Then we can, separately, iterate over that to do whatever downloading etc.
- We can use a comprehension again to do the filtering. We're skipping over things that are in the `links_in_file` *or* that are not 115 characters long; therefore we are *including things that are *not* in the `links_in_file` [*and*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) are 115 characters long.
- We'll do this in two steps to keep it simpler to understand: first we'll extract the `'src'` data, and then do the filtering. (This way, we avoid writing `tag['src']` a bunch of times in the following code.)

So:

```
new_links = {tag['src'] for tag in img}
filtered_links = {
    link for link in new_links
    if link not in links_in_file and len(link) == 115
}
```

This approach accounts for the fact that there might be multiple satisfactory links. Now we can update the links file with them all at once:

```
links_file.write(links_file.read() + '\n' + '\n'.join(filtered_links))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand problem - you want to skip only links which you already have in file but download other links - then you should do it inside `else:`

```
# --- read all links ---

convert_links = open("Links.txt", "r")
known_links = convert_links.read().split('\n')
convert_links.close()

# --- process ---

all_images = page_soup.findAll("img")

for index, link in enumerate(all_images):
    src = link["src"]
    if src in known_links or len(src) != 115:
        print("Found")
    else:
        # append link to list
        known_links.append(src)
        # download image with unique name
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, f"firstmeme-{index}.jpg")

# --- write back all links (with new links) ---

convert_links = open("Links.txt", "w")
convert_links.write('\n'.join(known_links))
convert_links.close()
```

---

**BTW:** you can write `if` in different way

```
if src not in known_links and len(src) == 115:
    # append link to list
    known_links.append(src)
    # download image with unique name
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, f"firstmeme-{index}.jpg")
```

---

**EDIT:**

Your `for`-loop is useless. `break` skips loops but it never skip `urlretrieve` because `urlretrieve` is after `for`-loop. You could remove `for`-loop and it would give the same result.

Other problem is that `urlretrieve` is executed only once even if you have many new links because `urlretrieve` is after `for`-loop. If you want to download many links then it has to be inside `for`-loop.

Problem is keeping new links. You save it but you don't add it to `dic` - if this link is many times in `img` then it will download it again and again because `if scr in dic` will not stop it.

Last thing. I don't like to read and write at the same time because sometimes it can works in wrong way. I prefer to read all and close file, and later open again only to write it.

And one thig: using dictionary only to use keys seems useless - I use list to keeps links from file.

Comment: I added some comments